# Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty s tring

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I am new to ShellScript. Here is my code to remove 'ONEWORD' from mentioned path: if I don't introduce space in the filename, its working as expected. But if there is space in filename, it's throwing below error:

**Program:**

```
call:DoReplace "ONEWORD" "" "C:\Users\yeturukr\Desktop\Test\Dest\CMD COMET.txt" "C:\Users\yeturukr\Desktop\Test\Dest\CMD COMET.txt"
  exit /b

  :DoReplace
  echo ^(Get-Content "%3" ^) ^| ForEach-Object { $_ -replace %1, %2 } ^| Set-Content %4 >Rep.ps1
  Powershell.exe -executionpolicy ByPass -File Rep.ps1
  if exist Rep.ps1 del Rep.ps1
  echo Done
  pause
```

**Error:**

> Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is
>   an empty s tring. At C:\Users\yeturukr\Desktop\Test\Rep.ps1:1 char:13
>   + (Get-Content <<<<  ""C:\Users\yeturukr\Desktop\Test\Dest\CMD COMET_APIN002234
>   _20161025_0745_1.txt"" ) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "BARCAP", "" } | Set-Co ntent "C:\Users\yeturukr\Desktop\Test\Dest\CMD
>   COMET_APIN002234_20161025_0745_1 .txt"
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBinding    ValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAl
>   lowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Answer (score 1):

`echo Get-Content "%3"` results to something like `Get-Content ""…\CMD COMET.txt""` with **doubled** double quotes (invalid path specification).

Apply [Parameter Extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) as follows:

```
:DoReplace
echo ^(Get-Content "%~3" ^) ^| ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "%~1", "%~2" } ^| Set-Content "%~4" >Rep.ps1
```

Now you have full control of using double quotes.

**Edit**: made a complex sample script for proof that above works:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "_fileIn=%userprofile%\Desktop\Test\Dest\CMD COMET.txt"
set "_fileOu=%userprofile%\Desktop\Test\Dest\CMD COMET.txt"

rem csteate sample files
md "%userprofile%\Desktop\Test\Dest\" 2>NUL
 >"%_fileOu%" type NUL
 >"%_fileIn%" echo 1st line 
>>"%_fileIn%" echo 2nd oneword
>>"%_fileIn%" echo 3rd line
type "%_fileIn%"

call:DoReplace "ONEWORD" "" "%_fileIn%" "%_fileOu%"

  type "%_fileOu%"
  exit /b

:endlocal
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

  :DoReplace
  echo ^(Get-Content "%~3" ^) ^| ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "%~1", "%~2" } ^| Set-Content "%~4" >Rep.ps1
  Powershell.exe -executionpolicy ByPass -File Rep.ps1
  REM type Rep.ps1
  if exist Rep.ps1 del Rep.ps1
  echo Done
  goto :eof
```

**Output**:

```
==> D:\bat\SO\40233525.bat
1st line
2nd oneword
3rd line
Done
1st line
2nd
3rd line

==>
```

Comment: JosefZ, i got error while trying ths. Error:    Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\yeturukr\Desktop\Test\Dest\.txt' becau
se it does not exist.

Comment: Please double check your script. Looks like expanded `%~dpx3` or `%~dpx4`. Should be as advised e.g. `%~3` or could be `%~dpnx3` or `%~f3`.

Comment: THanks a lot JosefZ. your code works. I made a mistake while writing code.